# function on javascript can't remove

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how to remove ALL DOM in specific id, we know http://jsfiddle.net can test javascript for all condition.

directory file:

```
\root
\root\index.php
\root\load.php
```

index.php have script tag id='index' and this index.php using .load() (jQuery) for load.php, in load.php have script tag id='load',

i try use this method (in load.php for clean DOM from index.php):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#index").remove();
});
```

but this not remove DOM Function, why??

EDIT : 
This trouble is DOM cant be remove

i needed is delete a < script id='index' > and DOM Function (ALL FROM THIS TAG) if i loaded "load.php"

Comment: Once it's loaded you can't remove it using javascript.. Perhaps use php to remove it before it loads..

Comment: Your jsfiddle link leads to the homepage of jsfiddle.  Additionally you should only have **one** element per id. If you want multiple items to share the same id, use classes instead.  Or do you mean remove the contents of an id.  If so, simply use, `$("#index").html("")` to set the dom to empty.

Comment: @Rick 2  thanks for infor. but if possible using php, please show me example.

Comment: you just don't have enough info to answer..

Comment: @nfn neil thanks for infor. I've tried if i using index.php loading a load.php from div tag id='dom' `$("#dom").load("load.php");` and in load.php back to index.php using same method, this have DOUBLE DOM in HTML Doc.

Comment: Okay, I added a post with how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use multiple elements with same `id` if you want to do so you need to use **classes** instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".index").remove();
});
```

**UPDATE**

if what you want to hide your script when you load another file you could do so by surrounding your script between a **div** to hide for example:

```
 <div class="divtohide">
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $("button").click(function(){
                 $(".test").load("load.php");
              });
           });
      </script>
 </div>
```

and in your load.php you could create a script to remove the `.divtohide` div:

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".divtohide").remove();
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but maybe you not understand my questtion, i have edited my question, i must delete all dom function, thanks again for @Amr Aly

Comment: this good thanks for you, but this method can't to clean all DOM in HTML doc, this method only clean the tag, look at this http://i65.tinypic.com/2pqqdro.png

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript will be run at `.load()`.  So, we need to remove the string before loading the content into the webpage.  I decided to use `$.get`, which will fetch the information as text.  Then I run the data through a regex that will remove `script#index`.  From there, I then append it to the page (for testing).  If you notice there is no `console.log`'s despite it being in the source of `removeIndex.html`, that's because we have successfully removed the JavaScript at `script#index`.

```js
$.get("http://neil.computer/stack/removeIndex.html", function (data) {
 data = data.replace(/<script.+?id=["']index["'](.|[\r\n])*?<\/script>/gi,"");
 $("#container").html(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**removeIndex.html**

This file has some sample input:

```
<div>
    Testing stuff
</div>

<script id="index">
    console.log("ignore me");
</script>

<div>
    Testing more stuff
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but maybe you not understand my questtion, i have edited my question, i must delete all dom function, thanks again for @nfn neil

Comment: Do you want to prevent it from executing completely?  I would use regex and then load it into the page.

Comment: yes, i want to clean all, if your method work, use anything (web application programming only ) thanks for responded :) **(this link using only clean the tag but dom can't to clean** http://i65.tinypic.com/2pqqdro.png **)**

Comment: thanks..., i dont understand some code, but i have question. What is Point to remove a DOM :)

Comment: I guess you can just remove the insides... but why?  You would then just have an empty `script` tag.  You should just append it in your JavaScript/HTML.

Comment: in this syntax `data = data.replace(/<script.+?id=["']index["'](.|[\r\n])*?<\/script>/gi,"");` <- this regex right? but i can't understand why using this? and please using ajax method? you like show me please i can't troubleshoot this :)

Comment: You should look into REGEX and you'll be fine.  I use https://regex101.com/ when trouble shooting regex's.  You can easily change the method to `.ajax`, but I think it is best you learn how to do that.

Comment: this a idea index.php use java $.ajax for load other page, is other page (load.php) his delete DOM from index.php